# Execute js when document.body exists

Tags: javascript

I have some script in document HEAD section like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Tests</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mySpan = document.createElement("span");
        mySpan.innerHTML = "This is my span!";

        mySpan.style.color = "red";
        document.body.appendChild(mySpan);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In this script i want to add element to body, but it fails with *document.body is null* exception. I understand that body doesn't exist at this time. But i still need do this operation, because a can't insert this script to body, it restricted by API, i haven't access to all site code.

And important one: i need do this before window will be loading (i mean window.load event).

Can I do this?

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: want to use "body" element before window.onload?? No way. because DOM is not yet constructed and hence body element wont exist

Comment: @vivek_nk actually `body` element exists immediately after parser has met starting `body` tag.

Comment: yeah. But he wants even before that he says. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use `Jquery` you can use `DOMContentLoaded` [see reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var mySpan = document.createElement("span");
    mySpan.innerHTML = "This is my span!";
    mySpan.style.color = "red";
    document.body.appendChild(mySpan);
});
```

**Browser supported :**

```
Chrome     Firefox (Gecko)         IE   Opera   Safari

0.2         1.0 (1.7 or earlier)   9.0  9.0     3.1
```

Comment: This adds the `span` at the end of the `body`, is it the place you want it to appear?

Comment: I need in body, no matter where

Comment: But, what if the network is slow, and takes a really really long time to load the document (all content in the body), then how do we execute code when `document.body` is specifically available, not having to wait for the document to be loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I usually avoid using frameworks unless absolutely necessary, but in this instance I think you could use jquery:

```
$(function () {
    // do stuff after DOM has loaded
});
```

So, wrap your code like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var mySpan = document.createElement("span");
    mySpan.innerHTML = "This is my span!";

    mySpan.style.color = "red";
    document.body.appendChild(mySpan);
});
</script>
```

Remember you will need to reference jQuery

This is not the same as `window.onload` - `onload` executes after all other resources have been loaded (images etc.)

The code I showed in my example will execute when the DOM has finished loading

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the fastest way to detect when `document.body` is available is with `MutationObserver`, as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26324641/454780