# Wait for document.body existence

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-handling, dom-events

I wrote a Chrome extension that works before the page is loaded (using the attribute `"run_at": "document_start"`).
The problem is that I want to add a `div` tag to the web page body as soon as it is created.
Before that `document.body` is null so I can't append tags to it.

I don't care about full load of the body, I just need it to be existent.

I am trying to find the best way to be alerted when the `body` tag in html is created (not loaded fully, just created). Is there any event handler for this case that I can write?

Also, I don't want to use `jQuery` or any other non built-in library.

Answer (score 23):

You could use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on `document.documentElement` listening for changes to its `childList` and looking to see whether the thing that got added is `body`.

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/qowoqu/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <script>
    (function() {
      "use strict";

      var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
        if (document.body) {
          // It exists now
          document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
            "beforeend",
            "<div>Found <code>body</code></div>"
          );
          observer.disconnect();
        }
      });
      observer.observe(document.documentElement, {childList: true});
    })();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="foo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `DOMContentLoaded` event which is similar to `$(document).ready()`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
});
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) says

> The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when the `document` has been
>   completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images,
>   and subframes to finish loading (the `load` event can be used to detect
>   a fully-loaded page).

Comment: The author said that he _"doesn't care about full load of the body"_, he _"just needs it to be existent"_. But the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired after the **full load** of the `document`, it means after `</body>`. @tjcrowder's answer is exactly what @ygandelsman needed.

Comment: Just to add here that if you look at the official documentation there is a case that the event has fired before your script had the chance to hook itself to the event. So if you need to handle this check this out - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event#checking_whether_loading_is_already_complete